# MissingSuperCall in lint on android skips some situations

Tags: java, android, xml, lint

In my code, I have something like the following:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity aActivity) {
    //super.onAttach(aActivity);
  }

... some more code ...
}
```

It appears that even with the following configuration, lint misses that this class doesn't call the `super.onAttach()` method from within `onAttach()`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <!-- Disable the given check in this project -->
    <issue id="MissingSuperCall" severity="fatal" />
</lint>
```

My question here is twofold:

1. Why is lint skipping this obvious error that should be marked as fatal?
2. If, as is my suspicion, that this isn't a method that lint checks (i.e. the `onAttach()` method of `Fragment`), then is there a way to get lint to flag this method as well (i.e. some deeper configuration, or, barring that, at the least an issue reporting mechanism for improving lint)?

Answer (score 0):

1) Probably because you're listing it in the lint.xml file. This makes Android Lint ignore that particular error. Its mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html).

> The lint.xml file
>       A configuration file that you can use to specify any lint checks that you want to exclude and to customize problem severity levels.

2) As far as flagging a method goes, you'll need to follow [this](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules). It tells you how to create a lint check for Android code. Thereafter, you could make use of the `JavaScanner` interface. Source can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.android.tools.lint/lint_api/r16/com/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Detector.java#Detector.JavaScanner). You can override the `visitMethod` API and visit instructions within the `onAttach` function. There you can check for a `super.onAttach` call. If not found, you can flag an error.